# Link click works in browser, but not in android webview - IONIC

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webview

I'm trying to download blob files from my rest api. The code works when running in browser, but when i try to use in android app, the code does nothing. And dont show any errors.

See the code below:

```
this.documentService.getURLDocumentConverted(documentMain.DOCUMENT.ID_DOCUMENT).subscribe(
      response => {
          var file = new Blob([response.body], { type: 'application/pdf' });
          var link = document.createElement('a');

          link.href = (window.URL || (window as any).webkitURL || window || {}).createObjectURL(file);
          link.download = fileName + ".pdf";
          link.click();
      }
```

Comment: are you getting any error or warning. check your console

Comment: Usuall app's need "only on user request" for some high priority action.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari no errors or warnings in console! :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting a `WebViewClient`. By default, clicking links will send intents to be handled by apps with matching intent filters (usually, you only see browser apps). I would guess no apps register intent filters for the `blob://` scheme, so nothing handles the intent (hence, no visible reaction to the click).

Setting a default-constructed `WebViewClient` changes the behavior: WebView will handle navigations itself.

This is described in the [API reference for `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%2520android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)).

Comment: Are u saying to add private webview: WebView in my download class? I try that using the import { WebView } from '@ionic-native/ionic-webview/ngx' and not working. Do you have some example code?

Comment: I'm talking about the underlying Java APIs. You should look up how to do the equivalent in the ionic framework.